# Tensorflow instalation on Windows 10 Intel Core i3 Processor with nVIDIA GEFORCE 920M GPU

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, tensorflow

I am trying to install using the instructions [here](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-and-run-gpu-enabled-tensorflow-on-windows/)

I have a compatible nVIDIA GEFORCE 920M GPU and the CRUD DNN toolkit and the driver both installed on the System.
when I do the step on the python program to test tensorflow installation on GPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

The output I get is:

```
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
2017-05-28 09:38:01.349304: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-   
win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] 
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these 
are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.


2017-05-28 09:38:01.349459: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release- 
win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] 
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these 
are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

2017-05-28 09:38:01.349583: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-
win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45]  
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these 
are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

2017-05-28 09:38:01.349705: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-
win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] 
The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these 
are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

2017-05-28 09:38:01.354312: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-
win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:257] Device mapping:
```

My pin pointed questions to you are:

1. Why is the nVIDIA GPU not getting detected when all librariries and toolkits are installed without errors?
2. Why is it the output saying "TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these 
   are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations" and how do i rectify this?
3. Please give a step by step solution. None other.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my pinpointed answers:

```
Why is the nVIDIA GPU not getting detected when all librariries and toolkits are installed without errors?
```

Ans: Go to NVidia GEFORCE Application and update the driver then the libraries will start getting detected and the errors will go away.

```
Why is it the output saying "TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations" and how do i rectify this?
```

Ans: Once you have done the above update the TensorFlow Library will stop giving the SSE errors. This will resolve your issue.

```
Please give a step by step solution. None other.
```

Ans: Given above should work it has worked for me.

Comment: This has worked for me too. Thanks for your pin pointed answer @Hillary